# How to form a regex by combining multiple regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hi i have a requirement where i want to  form a regex based on

1. match whole word if it starts with given word in regex
2. match whole double quotes enclosed word
3. match word inside (..), [..],{..} if word starts with given word in regex - will be similar as (1) except within brackets

Here is how i formed regex

- for 1) `\s*(pattern)\s*\S` demo: https://regex101.com/r/dFHTtv/2
- for 2) and 3) `(?<=[\(|\[|"])\s*(virat kohli|virat|kohli)\s*(?=([\]|\)|"]))` demo: https://regex101.com/r/aOox5A/3

i want to combine them so that it will work perfectly

here is what i have tried

```js
var searchString = `virat "virat kohli" regarded ipl`;
var keywordList = searchString.split(/\s+/g);
var exactSearchList = searchString.match(/(?<=").*?(?=")/g);

var textDescription = `<pre>Virat Kohli (About this soundpronunciation (help·info); born 5 November 1988) is an Indian cricketer and the current captain of the India national team. A right-handed top-order batsman, Kohli is regarded as one of the best batsmen in the world.[3] He plays for Royal Challengers Bangalore in the Indian Premier League (IPL), and has been the team's captain since 2013. Since October 2017, he has been the top-ranked ODI batsman in the world and is currently 2nd in Test rankings with 886 points.[4][5] Among Indian batsmen, Kohli has the best ever Test rating (937 points), ODI rating (911 points) and T20I rating (897 points). 

  virat kohli is one of best performer in ipl

(virat )  (kohli)   

 kohli is good player virat virat kohli kohli

custom kohli virat virat kohli kohli virat "virat kohli"

 "virat kohli" "kohli virat" "virat"
"kohli"

Kohli captained India Under-19s to victory at the 2008 Under-19 World Cup in Malaysia. After a few months later, he made his ODI debut for India against Sri Lanka at the age of 19. Initially having played as a reserve batsman in the Indian team, he soon established himself as a regular in the ODI middle-order and was part of the squad that won the 2011 World Cup. He made his Test debut in 2011 and shrugged off the tag of "ODI specialist" by 2013 with Test hundreds in Australia and South Africa.[6] Having reached the number one spot in the ICC rankings for ODI batsmen for the first time in 2013,[7] Kohli also found success in the Twenty20 format, winning the Man of the Tournament twice at the ICC World Twenty20 (in 2014 and 2016).

Kohli was appointed the vice-captain of the ODI team in 2012 and handed over the Test captaincy following Mahendra Singh Dhoni's Test retirement in 2014. In early 2017, he became the limited-overs captain as well after Dhoni stepped down from the position. In ODIs, Kohli has the second highest number of centuries and the highest number of centuries in run-chases in the world. He holds the world record for being the fastest batsman to 8,000, 9,000, 10,000 and 11,000 runs in ODI cricket, reaching the milestones in 175, 194, 205 and 222 innings respectively.[8][9] [10][11]

Kohli has been the recipient of many awards such as the Sir Garfield Sobers Trophy (ICC Cricketer of the Year) in 2017 and 2018; ICC Test Player of the Year 2018; ICC ODI Player of the Year in 2012, 2017 and 2018 and Wisden Leading Cricketer in the World in 2016, 2017 and 2018.[12] He was given the Arjuna Award in 2013, the Padma Shri under the sports category in 2017[13] and the Rajiv Gandhi Khel Ratna, the highest sporting honour in India, in 2018.[14] Kohli is ranked as one of the world's most famous athletes by ESPN[15] and one of the most valuable athlete brands by Forbes.[16] In 2018, Time magazine named Kohli one of the 100 most influential people in the world.[17] In 2020, Kohli was ranked 66th in Forbes list of the top 100 highest paid athletes in the world for the year 2020 with estimated earnings of $26 million. Virat Kohli is the only cricketer to feature in Forbes.[18]</pre>`;


  var exactSearchListTemp = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < exactSearchList.length; i++){
     if(String(exactSearchList[i]).trim() != '')
      exactSearchListTemp.push(String(exactSearchList[i]).trim());
        }
        if(Array.isArray(exactSearchList) && exactSearchList.length) keywordList = keywordList.concat(exactSearchListTemp);
        var convertedRegex = keywordList.filter(function(el){
            return  el.replace(/\|/g,'');
        }).join('|');
        var pattern = new RegExp(`((?<=(^|\\s|^\\[?.*\\W]?|^\\()|^{?)(?:${convertedRegex}))\\S*`, 'ig');
        var highlightDesc = textDescription.replace(pattern, '<highlight>$&</highlight>');
       
$('#matchedContainer').html(highlightDesc);
```

```css
#matchedContainer{
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   width:100%;
   height:400px;
}

highlight{
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="matchedContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Try `/(?<=[(["]\s*|\b)(virat(?: kohli)?|kohli)(?=\b|\s*[\])"])/gi`, see [demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/nd8ha1/1). Or, `/(?<=[(["]\s*|\b)(?:vir|koh|regar)\w*(?=\b|\s*[\])"])/gi`, see [this demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/nd8ha1/2).

Comment: Seems to be matching but how can i put it dynamically?

Comment: Which version works? First one?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, i want to put it dynamically as my  match text will come from input field and description too.  i want to make regex dynamically.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, first one is matching perfectly

Comment: Ok, you need many more things to fix here. Please check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/ruotxz54/8/) and let me know if it is what you need.

Comment: Please check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/ruotxz54/8/) and let me know if it is what you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, please put your regex as answer to my question. i will try to make it dynamically, thanks alot

Comment: The regex itself is very simple. Making it dynamic is rather intricate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could use a static regex you could use

```
/(?<=[(["]\s*|\b)(virat(?: kohli)?|kohli)(?=\b|\s*[\])"])/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nd8ha1/1).

**Details**

- `(?<=[(["]\s*|\b)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with `(`, `[` or `"` and then having any zero or more whitespace chars, or a word boundary
- `(virat(?: kohli)?|kohli)` - a capturing group matching either `virat kohli` or `virat` or `kohli`
- `(?=\b|\s*[\])"])` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with a word boundary or any zero or more whitespaces followed with `]`, `)` or `"`.

My JavaScript attempt to build the pattern dynamically (assuming the keywords to search for are provided in the `searchString`, where words inside double quotes are to be searched as a single keyword):

```js
var textDescription = "<pre>Virat Kohli (About this soundpronunciation (help·info); born 5 November 1988) is an Indian cricketer and the current captain of the India national team. A right-handed top-order batsman, Kohli is regarded as one of the best batsmen in the world.[3] He plays for Royal Challengers Bangalore in the Indian Premier League (IPL), and has been the team's captain since 2013. Since October 2017, he has been the top-ranked ODI batsman in the world and is currently 2nd in Test rankings with 886 points.[4][5] Among Indian batsmen, Kohli has the best ever Test rating (937 points), ODI rating (911 points) and T20I rating (897 points). \n\n  virat kohli is one of best performer in ipl\n\n(virat )  (kohli)   \n\n kohli is good player virat virat kohli kohli\n\ncustom kohli virat virat kohli kohli virat \"virat kohli\"\n\n \"virat kohli\" \"kohli virat\" \"virat\"\n\"kohli\"\n\nKohli captained India Under-19s to victory at the 2008 Under-19 World Cup in Malaysia. After a few months later, he made his ODI debut for India against Sri Lanka at the age of 19. Initially having played as a reserve batsman in the Indian team, he soon established himself as a regular in the ODI middle-order and was part of the squad that won the 2011 World Cup. He made his Test debut in 2011 and shrugged off the tag of \"ODI specialist\" by 2013 with Test hundreds in Australia and South Africa.[6] Having reached the number one spot in the ICC rankings for ODI batsmen for the first time in 2013,[7] Kohli also found success in the Twenty20 format, winning the Man of the Tournament twice at the ICC World Twenty20 (in 2014 and 2016).\n\nKohli was appointed the vice-captain of the ODI team in 2012 and handed over the Test captaincy following Mahendra Singh Dhoni's Test retirement in 2014. In early 2017, he became the limited-overs captain as well after Dhoni stepped down from the position. In ODIs, Kohli has the second highest number of centuries and the highest number of centuries in run-chases in the world. He holds the world record for being the fastest batsman to 8,000, 9,000, 10,000 and 11,000 runs in ODI cricket, reaching the milestones in 175, 194, 205 and 222 innings respectively.[8][9] [10][11]\n\nKohli has been the recipient of many awards such as the Sir Garfield Sobers Trophy (ICC Cricketer of the Year) in 2017 and 2018; ICC Test Player of the Year 2018; ICC ODI Player of the Year in 2012, 2017 and 2018 and Wisden Leading Cricketer in the World in 2016, 2017 and 2018.[12] He was given the Arjuna Award in 2013, the Padma Shri under the sports category in 2017[13] and the Rajiv Gandhi Khel Ratna, the highest sporting honour in India, in 2018.[14] Kohli is ranked as one of the world's most famous athletes by ESPN[15] and one of the most valuable athlete brands by Forbes.[16] In 2018, Time magazine named Kohli one of the 100 most influential people in the world.[17] In 2020, Kohli was ranked 66th in Forbes list of the top 100 highest paid athletes in the world for the year 2020 with estimated earnings of $26 million. Virat Kohli is the only cricketer to feature in Forbes.[18]</pre>";

const searchString = `virat "virat kohli" regarded ipl`;
const keywordList = searchString.match(/[^\s"]+|"[^"]+"/g).map(x => x.replace(/"/g, ''));
keywordList.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
const pattern = new RegExp(String.raw`(?<=[(["]\s*|\b)(${keywordList.join("|")})(?=\b|\s*[\])"])`, 'ig');
const highlightDesc = textDescription.replace(pattern, '<highlight>$&</highlight>');
       
$('#matchedContainer').html(highlightDesc);
```

```css
#matchedContainer{
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   width:100%;
   height:400px;
}

highlight{
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="matchedContainer"></div>
```

Here, the pattern is built like this:

```js
const keywordList = searchString.match(/[^\s"]+|"[^"]+"/g).map(x => x.replace(/"/g, ''));
keywordList.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
const pattern = new RegExp(String.raw`(?<=[(["]\s*|\b)(${keywordList.join("|")})(?=\b|\s*[\])"])`, 'ig');
```

Another variation of the code, where the list of keywords is a list of unique words that is a result of removing `"` from `searchString` and splitting with whitespace:

```
const keywordList = [...new Set(searchString.replace(/"/g, '').split(/\s+/))];
```

```js
var textDescription = "<pre>Virat Kohli (About this soundpronunciation (help·info); born 5 November 1988) is an Indian cricketer and the current captain of the India national team. A right-handed top-order batsman, Kohli is regarded as one of the best batsmen in the world.[3] He plays for Royal Challengers Bangalore in the Indian Premier League (IPL), and has been the team's captain since 2013. Since October 2017, he has been the top-ranked ODI batsman in the world and is currently 2nd in Test rankings with 886 points.[4][5] Among Indian batsmen, Kohli has the best ever Test rating (937 points), ODI rating (911 points) and T20I rating (897 points). \n\n  virat kohli is one of best performer in ipl\n\n(virat )  (kohli)   \n\n kohli is good player virat virat kohli kohli\n\ncustom kohli virat virat kohli kohli virat \"virat kohli\"\n\n \"virat kohli\" \"kohli virat\" \"virat\"\n\"kohli\"\n\nKohli captained India Under-19s to victory at the 2008 Under-19 World Cup in Malaysia. After a few months later, he made his ODI debut for India against Sri Lanka at the age of 19. Initially having played as a reserve batsman in the Indian team, he soon established himself as a regular in the ODI middle-order and was part of the squad that won the 2011 World Cup. He made his Test debut in 2011 and shrugged off the tag of \"ODI specialist\" by 2013 with Test hundreds in Australia and South Africa.[6] Having reached the number one spot in the ICC rankings for ODI batsmen for the first time in 2013,[7] Kohli also found success in the Twenty20 format, winning the Man of the Tournament twice at the ICC World Twenty20 (in 2014 and 2016).\n\nKohli was appointed the vice-captain of the ODI team in 2012 and handed over the Test captaincy following Mahendra Singh Dhoni's Test retirement in 2014. In early 2017, he became the limited-overs captain as well after Dhoni stepped down from the position. In ODIs, Kohli has the second highest number of centuries and the highest number of centuries in run-chases in the world. He holds the world record for being the fastest batsman to 8,000, 9,000, 10,000 and 11,000 runs in ODI cricket, reaching the milestones in 175, 194, 205 and 222 innings respectively.[8][9] [10][11]\n\nKohli has been the recipient of many awards such as the Sir Garfield Sobers Trophy (ICC Cricketer of the Year) in 2017 and 2018; ICC Test Player of the Year 2018; ICC ODI Player of the Year in 2012, 2017 and 2018 and Wisden Leading Cricketer in the World in 2016, 2017 and 2018.[12] He was given the Arjuna Award in 2013, the Padma Shri under the sports category in 2017[13] and the Rajiv Gandhi Khel Ratna, the highest sporting honour in India, in 2018.[14] Kohli is ranked as one of the world's most famous athletes by ESPN[15] and one of the most valuable athlete brands by Forbes.[16] In 2018, Time magazine named Kohli one of the 100 most influential people in the world.[17] In 2020, Kohli was ranked 66th in Forbes list of the top 100 highest paid athletes in the world for the year 2020 with estimated earnings of $26 million. Virat Kohli is the only cricketer to feature in Forbes.[18]</pre>";

const searchString = `virat "virat kohli" regarded ipl`;
const keywordList = [...new Set(searchString.replace(/"/g, '').split(/\s+/))];
keywordList.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
const pattern = new RegExp(String.raw`(?<=[(["]\s*|\b)(${keywordList.join("|")})(?=\b|\s*[\])"])`, 'ig');
const highlightDesc = textDescription.replace(pattern, '<highlight>$&</highlight>');
       
$('#matchedContainer').html(highlightDesc);
```

```css
#matchedContainer{
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   width:100%;
   height:400px;
}

highlight{
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="matchedContainer"></div>
```

Comment: sorry i went outside yesterday, to find this wonderful solution, thanks alot

Comment: sorry i forget to ask you yesterday below things
tester rejected it due to it is not satisfying if word starts with let say `var searchString = "vir"` it should match virat whole word even inside () like (virat) or [virat] .   

if `var searchString = "regar"` it should match whole word such as `regard`, `regarded`,[`regarded`],(`regarded`) etc 

i tried to accomodate it whole day but it was breaking something else, if you like to help me, then please

Basically i meant it should match whole word or if it starts with part of the word

Comment: @Learner ``(?<=[(["]\s*|\b)(${keywordList.join("|")}\w*)(?=\b|\s*[\])"])``